# Is it a good practice to customize nopcommerce in the code base?

Tags: nopcommerce

I am new to the nopcommerce development. One thing I noticed about in the first place is that, to custom the system(adding fields to category, product), I must edit the official code. I am not sure with this approach,  especially when I think about the upgrading in the future.  But seems this is the only way? Can anyone share with me your points on this topic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not a good idea to change base code.
And also it depends on how you change.

Some tips on changing base code

- make sure the signature of base methods remains the same. Else this will break lots of plugins.
- create new method if you need to change signature of base method.

And last, you should really try writing plugins. If you see the nopcommerce code plugins are injected everywhere you would need. I personally find it cleaner and easier(after a phase) to write code when creating plugin.